# Auto merging/snapping vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, snapping

I've done this a million times and in my current project - i have a L shaped mesh, extruding to fill in with more mesh if this makes sense. i've attached a picture, the 2nd vertice snapped to the vertice on the left instead of the first one snapping to it. I don't know why its doing this. i've done it a million times and i'm sure i'm having a brain fart and something is going on .... thanks for any input.[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't really understand it either many times. The default setting of *Snapping* is *Snap With* > *Closest*, the problem is I often cannot deliberately decide which vertices should be checked if they are closer, I try moving the mouse next to the desired vertex before moving, but to no avail. Maybe someone here can enlighten me on this.

But what usually works flawless for me is if I change from *Closest* to *Active*. This way I just have to make sure that the vertex I want to snap to another one is the active one (which in your screenshot is the one shown white instead of orange). With this setting I always know which vertex will be snapped to the closest other vertex, no matter where my mouse is or which other vertices are closer to anything.

Comment: will change to active and see how that goes ... thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your snapping mode. If the centre vertex was closer, that might be why it's snapping to the other vertex. Try moving it away first then move it back in order to reset this. Other than that, if possible, try moving only one vertex at a time.

Comment: will try thank you :)